# Gnu Screen: "type" in all windows at once

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510673/in-screen-how-do-i-send-a-command-to-all-virtual-terminal-windows-within-a-sing) on SO about the `stuff` command in screen.

It's pretty useful, but I wondered if there was a way to actually **interactively** type into multiple windows at once? - `stuff` seems to be very useful for one window, but is onptimized for one shot commands; I wondered if there was anyting more interactive (for example for parallel `vi` sessions, or for quickly shooting off commands in sequence as you would on a normal terminal window)

if not, is it possible to do this with tmux or any of the other `screen`-like utilities?

-ace

Comment: I found this - http://www.tofu.org/drupal/node/181 - which is pretty close to what I want. I'm still interested though if this can be done in screen.

Comment: you can do somthing like that with terminator, a multi-terminal shell. you can launch a number of screens in seperate terminal windows and use terminator to send text to all of them or a subset thereof. http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html

Comment: Frank - this works perfectly - if you want to add as an answser instead of a comment, I'll accept & you'll get the credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that with terminator, a multi-terminal shell. you can launch a number of screens in separate terminals and use terminator to send text to all of them or a subset thereof. http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this in screen for shooting off multiple commands to all windows. It's a bit more convoluted than it probably should be.

Do the following...

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then press the colon key <kbd>:</kbd>. This will open a vi style prompt.

Type the following in to that prompt (this is an example of sending the `ls` command to all windows)

```
at "#" stuff "ls^M"
```

Then hit enter.

Also keep in mind that you can have it send multiple commands in succession, just split each up with ^M at the end of it (which represents sending a return).  Example...

```
at "#" stuff "cd /^Mls^Mcd /home^Mls^M"
```